# WPF TextBox doesn't refresh despite binding and INotifyPropertyChangeduse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I did a little WPF window with a button and a textBox.

When I click on the button, there is some stuff, then I add some lines to my TextBox.

I often did this kind of apps with Winform and when I did them, the UI refreshed each time the textbox was updated, but not in my WPF application.

So I read about and did binding and used the INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private string myValue;
    public string MyValue
    {
        get { return myValue; }
        set
        {
            myValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyValue");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // 
    //.......
    //
}
```

Then my XAML :

```
<TextBox  x:Name="TxtBox_result" Text="{Binding Path=MyValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="30,332,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="868" Height="285" TextChanged="TxtBox_result_TextChanged" />
```

I know there is probably cleaner code to do with MVVM approach but I don't know MVVM but would like to try first to have a simple method to refresh my UI. It's a shame because it was easier in Win32.

---

Here is the code executed when i click on the button, i update the MyValue on these code but the TextBox only show value when the treatment is over :

```
private void GenererBases (string DirectoryStd, string DirectorySur)
{
int cpt = 0;

bool bSignatureBaseFound = false;
bool bFirst = true;
string strDirectoryOut = string.Empty;

var files =  Directory.GetFiles(DirectorySur, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
.Where(s => s.EndsWith(".txt") || s.EndsWith(".dat"));

MyValue = " ";
MyValue = " > Recherche des fichiers ...." + Environment.NewLine;

foreach (string fileName in files)
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    string FileNameStandard = string.Empty;
    bSignatureBaseFound = false;

    MyValue = MyValue + Environment.NewLine + " > Extraction de la signature du fichier base pour : " + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);


    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("SetModuleInfo('$Id:"))
        {
            bSignatureBaseFound = true;
            int posDebFichier = line.IndexOf("'$Id:") + 6;
            int posFinFichier = line.IndexOf(" ", (line.IndexOf("'$Id:") + 6));

            FileNameStandard = line.Substring(posDebFichier, posFinFichier-posDebFichier); 

            if (File.Exists(DirectoryStd+@"\"+FileNameStandard))
            {
                MyValue = MyValue + Environment.NewLine + " > Fichier base : " + FileNameStandard + " localisé ! > Copie vers le dossier de destination !";
                
                if (bFirst)
                {
                    strDirectoryOut = DirectorySur + @"\Generated_bases_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirectoryOut);
                    bFirst = false;
                }

                cpt++;

                if (File.Exists(strDirectoryOut + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileNameStandard) + "_base" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileNameStandard)))
                {
                    File.Delete(strDirectoryOut + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileNameStandard) + "_base" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileNameStandard));
                }
                File.Copy(DirectoryStd + @"\" + FileNameStandard, strDirectoryOut + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileNameStandard) + "_base" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileNameStandard),true);
                File.SetAttributes(strDirectoryOut + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileNameStandard) + "_base" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileNameStandard), File.GetAttributes(strDirectoryOut + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileNameStandard) + "_base" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileNameStandard)) | FileAttributes.Hidden);

            }
            else
            {
                MyValue = MyValue + Environment.NewLine + "!!! WARNING!!" + Environment.NewLine + "!!! Fichier base non localisé : " + FileNameStandard + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            break;
        }
        
    }
    file.Close();

    if (bSignatureBaseFound==false)
    {
        MyValue = MyValue + Environment.NewLine + "!!! WARNING!!" + Environment.NewLine + "!!! Aucune signature de base localisée pour : " + fileName + Environment.NewLine;

    }
    
}

MyValue = MyValue + Environment.NewLine + "***************************" + Environment.NewLine + "***************************" + Environment.NewLine + " >> Fin du traitement !" + cpt + " fichiers bases générés pour " + files.Count() + " sources surchargés !" + Environment.NewLine + ">> Fichiers bases copiés dans le dossier :" + strDirectoryOut + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no error in this code.
Show how you determined that there is no auto-update of the view?

Comment: "When i click on the button, there is some stuff then i add some lines to my TextBox" - some imaginary button? there are no buttons in the code above

Comment: @Ash, yeah i didn't posted the whole code. My button read some files on hardisk the it populate the MyValue many times. The values in the textbox only comes when the treatments on the button is finished.

Comment: @EldHasp Yeah, when i click on my button i read some files on the hard disk then populate the MyValue many times with some Environnement.newline. My textBox only sho values when the treatment behind the button is finished.

Comment: So, when it refreshed at the end of your procedure, then the binding is working. Do you want to display intermediate results?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you are reading the file in the UI thread. GUI updates can also only be done on the UI thread. But since it is busy executing a function, the update will occur only after it is freed from the work that you loaded it with, that is, upon completion of the method execution.
In order for the GUI to be responsive, you need to use asynchronous methods so that the UI thread is only busy with the logic working directly with the UI elements.
If you show the code of your method, I can show you how to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace Core2022.SO.WalterFabioSimoni
{
    public partial class InpcWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected bool Set<T>(ref T propertyField, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));

            bool notEquals = !Equals(propertyField, newValue);
            if (notEquals)
            {
                propertyField = newValue;
                RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            }

            return notEquals;
        }
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName ?? string.Empty));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    }
    public partial class AsyncUpdateWindow : InpcWindow
    {
        public AsyncUpdateWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private string _myValue = string.Empty;

        public string MyValue
        {
            get => _myValue;
            set => Set(ref _myValue, value ?? string.Empty);
        }

        private static readonly Random random= new Random();
        private async void OnRestartAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement button = (UIElement)sender;
            button.SetCurrentValue(IsEnabledProperty, false);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                MyValue = random.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue).ToString();
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
            button.InvalidateProperty(IsEnabledProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<local:InpcWindow x:Class="Core2022.SO.WalterFabioSimoni.AsyncUpdateWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.WalterFabioSimoni"
                  mc:Ignorable="d"
                  Title="AsyncUpdateWindow" Height="300" Width="400"
                  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue}" Margin="10"/>
        </Viewbox>

        <Button Content="Restart" Click="OnRestartAsync"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</local:InpcWindow>
```

There are no calls to UI elements in your method code - this is very good.
For your code, you just need to add the following method:

```cs
    private async void GenererBasesAsync(string DirectoryStd, string DirectorySur)
        => await Task.Run(() => GenererBases(DirectoryStd, DirectorySur));
```

In the clicker, call this async method.

Comment: Thanks a lot but why it's so complicated whereas it was si simple in WinForms :O

Comment: Thanks a lot, Asynch method works good ! Just have to find now how to scrollToEnd each time i add some lines.

Comment: WF was created a long time ago and does not have deep integration with «MV*» patterns. Therefore, there are many methods, ways to "manually control" the state of UI elements. Most of the solutions in WF are created, in fact, in the style of procedural programming. WPF, on the other hand, was created much later, when there was already a good understanding of how to correctly implement Solutions in OPP. Therefore, tools have already been added to WPF to make it easier to separate View and Model logic. Accordingly, the implementation of MVVM in WPF is much easier to create than in WF.

Comment: But for those migrating from WF, understanding the «MV*» patterns is often difficult. When you get enough knowledge and experience, you will understand how simple, more logical, more correct it is than what you did before. And you yourself will be surprised: “Why didn’t I do this before?”.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni , You need scroll down when updating TeatBox.Text. This can be done. I think you will find many solutions if you ask such a search.
If you still can't find a suitable solution for you, then create a new topic. Someone will answer. If I have free time, I will also join the discussion and give my answer.